# suggest me how to design schema for nested object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Please see the image, I have designed this schema, but not working

```
title: {
          type: [String],
          required: true,
          validate: (v) => Array.isArray(v) && v.length > 0,
        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DVXi.png

Comment: self-joining seems useful for you

Comment: You can define a sub schema - as schema within a schema - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schemas